# How can i include Charts into a pdf created with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, charts

I need to create a PDF with VBA. I have managed to do this. However, somehow it doesn't work quite right. Only tables are printed. The diagrams unfortunately not. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks for your help

Here is my Code:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
   Sheets("Tabelle1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Tabelle1")).Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, "_") - 1) & "-" & Format(Date, "mmm-d-yyyy") & "-" & Format(Time, "hh-mm-ss"), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
      True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the chart, press Ctrl+1 to format the Chart Area. Make sure the Print Object checkbox is checked.

[image: Format Chart Area Task Pane]